# Limit ElasticSearch to X results

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do something like in mySQL is the LIMIT operator. Let's say I want 10 results. In mySQL i do LIMIT 10 after the query. How do I achieve the same result in ElasticSearch? Right now Im trying "terminate_after":"10" but it doesn't work. It brings a lot more of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with size property:

```
GET /_search
{
     "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
     "query" : {}
}
```

More details you can find here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html